Install applications on a offline alpine docker image
I am in internship and i have to put an application, SimulIDE, in a docker image.
I work on a offline virtual machine on Debian 11  and i have the alpine docker image. Moreover, i have another computer windows, without docker and admin rights, connected to internet.
My question is : how and what packages can i download to install my application please ?
I don't find any packages for alpine and i don't find apk packages of my application.
Without docker on my connected computer it's really difficult.
I just want to create a docker image of SimulIDE witch works with Alpine.

You can't. You need internet access to download Docker images and Alpine packages. You could ask your organization's IT team to bridge your Virtual Machine's network so you can access the Internet from it, and be able to download the dependencies you need.
Developers frequently need admin privileges to install packages, dependencies, and software for their day-to-day duties. I'm sure the company you are working at already has an IT process set for when employees need to install software on their machines.
